# Is the current screen resolution saved to a file anywhere? (window 7)

Tags: file, window, resolution

i got another laptop but its not on hand now. I only have most of the files copied from that laptop on hand. May I know if I can find that file so that I can figure out the resolution using?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a question that should be asked on superuser.com; it does not seem to be about programming per se

Comment: thx, I just put this into superuser.com!